# Have Mongoid forget Observers

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongoid, observers

I am writing tests for my Mongoid document and observers separately. When I run rspec on my spec directory, my tests fail because the observer is still attached to my document class.

The Mongoid config code for my observer:

```
describe 'UserObserver' do
before :all do
    Mongoid.load! "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../mongoid.yml", :test

    Mongoid.observers = UserObserver
    Mongoid.instantiate_observers
end
...
end
```

And the Mongoid config code for my doc:

```
describe User do
before :all do
    Mongoid.load! "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../mongoid.yml", :test
end
...
end
```

I tried adding `Mongoid.observers.clear` to an `after:all` block but that didn't work. I've also tried a `Mongoid::config.reset` and that didn't work.

So, is it possible to remove an observer from Mongoid after it's been instantiated?

Comment: This is just a quick stab in the dark, but i'll add it as an answer if it works. Did you make sure you re-ran `Mongoid.instantiate_observers` after `Mongoid.observers.clear`?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, spoke too soon. I was mistaken; This does not seem to work when running all tests at once, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ack. That's unfortunate - sorry to get your hopes up :)